# How to filter a list of tuples in scala?

Tags: scala, filter, tuples, scala-collections

I have the following list in Scala which I want to filter based on a criteria such that if there are any tuples with duplicate first value ,
Like from the below example I want to exclude

```
List((a,1), (a,2))
```

since it is having have "a" as duplicate .

Comment: Do you want to remove both terms ((a,1) and (a,2)) or just one (filter the other one)? That one List((a,1), (a,2), (b,1), (b,2)) would yield an empty List, right?

Comment: At least try to not make it look like the Coursera Progfun coursework

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to filter your `result` with a function that only leaves untouched those lists with no duplicate "keys"

```
result filter noDuplicateKeys
```

This filtering function must take a list of pairs `List[(A,B)]` and return true only if the pair first element is not present elsewhere for all elements, and can be implemented as

```
def noDuplicateKeys[A, B](xs: List[(A, B)]) = 
    (xs groupBy (_._1)).values forall {_.size < 2}
```

It groups the elements into a `Map` whose keys are the `A`s and whose values are a corresponding list of the `B`s paired with that key.

From this values you can only accept those that have a size no more than 1

Comment: cool .. I was thinking on the same lines but was not able to comprehend in terms of scala , need to take all the keys , group them together and check if any is having count < 2 (xs groupBy (_._1)).values forall {_.size < 2} . Thanks for your help

Comment: Could you please explain to me how `(_._1).values` and `_.size` work? The use of `_.` really confuses me. It seems to me like In some contexts it helps avoid referring to an obvious thing like... if I'm filtering a list of Humans by minimum age,I would say something like `humans.filter(_.age > 18)` because that list would only have humans, and I think it also makes it more polymorphic, in case a list for instance has other things that humans and still I want to filter using the same criteria. Maybe I'm wrong or not, but still l don't get what goes on in your answer's code.

Comment: @newbie in this case `_._1` it's shorthand syntax for a function literal, a.k.a. anonymous function. It means you define a function on the fly without giving it a name.

In general the expanded syntax would be `x => x._1` and you pass it to the `groupBy` method like this: `xs.groupBy(x => x._1)`. 
The groupBy method expects a function as parameter and we feed it one. 
Since this function literal uses only one parameter once, we can avoid giving it a name using the `_` placeholder so

`x => x._1` is equivalent to `_._1`

Comment: @newbie You can learn more [here](http://ananthakumaran.in/2010/03/29/scala-underscore-magic.html)

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to clarify that I have a pretty good basic understanding of haskel, so I kinda know about the `_` operator, it confuses me in scala when it's combined with the `.` operator (of course haskel is purely functional unlike scala) I found that post you shared (earlier today) when researching about this question, but is a little too basic to understand what is going here, I believe what I didn't get was actually the groupBy function, but I've been playing with it a little and now it's all pretty clear! :)

Comment: @newbie well it's pretty understandable that the many uses of `_` confuses people all over, especially since in haskell you don't need any placeholder to write pointfree style, or to curry a function...

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the following code will do what you want (to remove only the first pair, right?):

I'm using pattern matching to do so, if you want to filter everything, u could do a recursion over your list or do what Kyle proposed. Check this out:

```
val a = "a"                                      
val b = "b"                                     

var result =
    List(
      List(),
      List((a, 1), (a, 2)),
      List((a, 1), (b, 1)),
      List((a, 1), (b, 2)),
      List((a, 2), (b, 1)),
      List((a, 2), (b, 2)),
      List((b, 1), (b, 2)),
      List((a, 1), (a, 2), (b, 1)),
      List((a, 1), (a, 2), (b, 2)),
      List((a, 1), (b, 1), (b, 2)),
      List((a, 2), (b, 1), (b, 2)),
      List((a, 1), (a, 2), (b, 1), (b, 2))) 

val filteredResult = (for (list <- result)
    yield list match {
    case x :: y :: xys if (x._1 == y._1) =>  xys
    case _ => list
  }).distinct
```

Result:

```
//> List()
//| List((a,1), (b,1))
//| List((a,1), (b,2))
//| List((a,2), (b,1))
//| List((a,2), (b,2))
//| List((b,1))
//| List((b,2))
//| List((a,1), (b,1), (b,2))
//| List((a,2), (b,1), (b,2))
//| List((b,1), (b,2))
```

The distinct will just filter the resulting empty lists.

Cheers!

Comment: i don't think that's right, you are comparing first two elements and keeping rest of the list. what if the match is between 2nd and 3rd elements?

Comment: Well, that's what I've understood from Shakti's question. I know where his question came from (Coursera ProgFun) and yes you have to do it through the whole list, in that case, my answer is not right. But, regarding his question, it was quite accurate, I believe. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I saw this as filtering out items from  `List[List[Tuple2[Char, Int]]]`  where an element of the list has the same elements. In this case an element of the list is `List[Tuple2[Char, Int]]` which I want to return a `Boolean` when the elements are the same. This `List[Tuple2[Char, Int]]` gets mapped to the first element of the `Tuple` and then logic is applied to the new list of chars using distinct and size to check if the elements are the same and to retain those that only have one element.

The filter

```
filter(xs => xs.map(ys => ys._1).distinct.size != 1 || xs.size == 1)
```

Test data:

```
scala> val a = List(List(('a',1)))
a: List[List[(Char, Int)]] = List(List((a,1)))

scala> val aa = List(List(('a',1),('a',1)))
aa: List[List[(Char, Int)]] = List(List((a,1), (a,1)))

scala> val ab = List(List(('a',1),('b',1)))
ab: List[List[(Char, Int)]] = List(List((a,1), (b,1)))

scala> val aba = List(List(('a',1),('b',1),('a',1)))
aba: List[List[(Char, Int)]] = List(List((a,1), (b,1), (a,1)))
```

Test cases.

```
scala> a.filter(xs => xs.map(ys => ys._1).distinct.size != 1 || xs.size == 1)
res34: List[List[(Char, Int)]] = List(List((a,1)))

scala> aa.filter(xs => xs.map(ys => ys._1).distinct.size != 1 || xs.size == 1)
res35: List[List[(Char, Int)]] = List()

scala> ab.filter(xs => xs.map(ys => ys._1).distinct.size != 1 || xs.size == 1)
res36: List[List[(Char, Int)]] = List(List((a,1), (b,1)))

scala> aba.filter(xs => xs.map(ys => ys._1).distinct.size != 1 || xs.size == 1)
res37: List[List[(Char, Int)]] = List(List((a,1), (b,1), (a,1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

based on the @pagoda_5b solution, I think we could find a better one.

What do you think about:

```
def noDuplicateKeys(l: List[(Char, Int)]): Boolean = l.toMap.size == l.size

list filter noDuplicateKeys
```

;)